# Merge multiple web projects into a single output zip package

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm using Visual Studio Online and working through building a continuous integration setup. The scenario I have requires that multiple web projects are built out to a single Azure App Service deployment.  The catch is that "out of the box" when you create a new build, the Visual Studio Build task appears to create a separate zip file for each project in the solution, and then the Azure App Service Deploy task throws an error saying there is more than one file matching the pattern, which is *.zip.

What I'd like to do is build all of these projects out to a single location, merging the various projects together, and then Azure App Service Deploy only has a single zip file to push, which I know it can do just fine. My MSBuild arguments for the Visual Studio Build task are `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`. I tried removing the `PackageAsSingleFile` attribute but it still created the zip files.

Is the scenario I want to do possible in VSO, perhaps with a different set of command codes?

Comment: Well, they changed the product name again, so Visual Studio Online is no long valid. If you do have multiple web  projects and want to deploy altogether, my suggestion is to use the Git based deployment, where you can easily organize the files in the folder structure you like. The deployment packages (based on Web Deployment Tool) are less customizable.

Comment: You're going to have trouble doing that -- Visual Studio builds based on one "web app" project == one zip file. Is there anything preventing you from using multiple app service deploy tasks in sequence to deploy all of the zip artifacts?

Comment: The big problem with multiple deploy tasks is we're talking about X number of projects, where X will change throughout the process. Having to add a new deploy task each time would be more cumbersome; I'd think there's some way to automate the process better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a PowerShell script or a few tasks, to manipulate the files and folders before publishing the artifact.

1. [Extract Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=vsts) `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\*.zip` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Merged`
2. [Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=vsts) `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Merged` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Merged.zip`
3. [Delete Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=vsts) that we extracted using minimatch: `!/**/*.zip`
4. Change your Azure App service deploy to look for: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/Merged.zip`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts

Comment: Unfortunately I am running into issues while extracting, extract fails on trying to extract archive.xml but the file is already extracted from a previous archive. Any ideas?

Comment: You have file name collision? That is causing Extract to fail?

Comment: Each zip file has its own archive.Xml and unfortunately the extract files task does not have a force override option.

I have worked around that by writing a powershell script. However the resulting merge is not cleanly deployed. The merged in projects keep their packageTmp directories and are not in the right location because of that.